# Argument not passing in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script where in the beginning of the code I created two simple functions to parse some strings:

```
Function createCase($subjid, $refids){
    $ret = @{}
    $ret.Add("subjid", $subjid)
    $ret.Add("refids", $refids)
    $ret.Add("subjents", @())
    $ret.Add("refents", @())

    return $ret
}

#Format input "subj;refid,refid,refid|subjid;refid,refid|subjid;refid"
function createCases($input){
    $ret = @{}
    $cases = $input.Split("|")
    foreach ($case in $cases) {
        $casearr = $case.Split(";")
        $caseobj = createCase($casearr[0], $casearr[1].Split(","))
        $ret.Add($casearr[0], $caseobj)
    }
    return $ret
}
```

Then a bit further I call upon this funcion `createCases($input)`:

```
$input = "subj;refid,refid,refid|subjid;refid,refid|subjid;refid"
$cases = createCases($input)
```

Yet the `$input` variable in my previously defined function doesn't get filled and I end up with an error:

> Method invocation failed because [System.Collections.ArrayList+ArrayListEnumeratorSimple] does not contain a method named 'Split'.

Which happens on the line:

```
$cases = $input.Split("|")
```

When I use the debugger the input argument is def set correctly to the string that I want it to be. Once we hop inside of the function it's gone.

Comment: @Default I've tried both "createCases($input)" and "createCases $input"

Comment: @Default That doesn't seem to change a thing. I still have an enmpty $input argument in the function

Comment: @Default that's what I also kind of assumed since it's refering to the Enumerator but when I go through debugging and inspect the contents of the variable $input" is empty and stepping over the line "$input.Split("|")" is what generates the error.

Comment: wait - "input" is reserved. try another name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's due to the name "input" which is reserved in Powershell. Rename that variable and it should work better.

For more information I can refer you to this article: 
https://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2008/11/26/input-gotchas/

Comment: Holy f*@#* &"'&'.. Thank you you're right. It works now. I would have assumed that PS ISE could produce some sort of warning if you tried to use reserved variables as an input argument. Thanks again